# Tensorflow error when using placeholder

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm beginner in tensorflow and i use it in implementing CNN on images and when i use palceholder with feed_dir it gives me error say

> You must Feed a value for placeholder

```
Grey_images = []
def Read_images(): 
    for filename in glob.glob(r'Path*.jpg'):
        img = Image.open(filename)
        img = img.convert('L')  # convert to gray scale
        img = np.asanyarray(img) 
        img_shape = img.shape
        img_reshaped = img.reshape(224,224,1 channels)
        Grey_images.append(img_reshaped)#[#imgs,224,224,1]

Read_images()
img = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,224,224,1])

def RunAll():
    layer = Layer(img,1,3,3,64,2,'Relu')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    Prediction = sess.run(RunAll(),feed_dict={img:Grey_images})
```

And this is **class layer**

```
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def Conv2d(inp, W ,Stride):

    return tf.nn.conv2d(inp, W, strides=[1, Stride ,Stride, 1], padding='SAME')

class Layer:
    def __init__(self, inp,inp_channels_num,filter_width_size,filter_height_size,outp_channels_num,stride,activation_func):
        sess = tf.Session()
        self.W_conv = weight_variable([filter_width_size, filter_height_size, inp_channels_num, outp_channels_num])
        self.b_conv = bias_variable([outp_channels_num])    
        if (activation_func=='Sigmoid'):
            self.h_conv = tf.nn.sigmoid(Conv2d(inp, self.W_conv, stride) + self.b_conv)
        else:
            self.h_conv = tf.nn.relu(Conv2d(inp, self.W_conv, stride) + self.b_conv)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())            
        self.h_conv = sess.run(self.h_conv)
        sess.close()
```

It gives me the error in this line however i use **feed_dir** in **sess.run(Runall())** so what am i missing ?

```
self.h_conv = sess.run(self.h_conv)
```

Answer (score 1):

The line where you run `self.h_conv` also needs a `feed_dict` provided.

Comment: If it is so what is the need of my ***feed_dict*** i saw it like this in Tensor.org  Toturials

Comment: It's because h_conv depends transitively on a placeholder, so when you evaluate it you need to provide the value of the placeholder.

Comment: okey and i provide it when calling function and send it to layer construction why it dont use it

Comment: In this toturial code he uses ***sess.run*** with the function without write it again with ***self.h_conv***, this is the link  http://codepad.org/BD1RLg2u  @Alexandre Passos

Comment: The tutorial doesn't have a like saying `sess.run(h_conv)`. If you remove that line your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

your whole program run on the same line, you haven't mentioned what the error is ?

## update

in function Read_images() you created have no return any value, so last line in function you should add 
`return Grey_images`

and you are not saving the values after you read images. 
in the program line `Read_lines()`
change to `Grey_images = Read_lines()`

Comment: I mentioned the Error at the first of the post 'You must Feed a value for placeholder'